What is the logical fallacy represented here
We can clearly see that there is no bi-univocal correspondence between linear signifying links or archi-writing, depending on the author, and this multireferential, multi-dimensional machinic cataly-sis. The symmetry of scale, the transversality, the pathic non-discursive character of their expansion: all these dimensions remove us from the logic of the excluded middle and reinforce us in our dismis-sal of the ontological binarism we criticised previously.

French philosopher Félix Guattari


Can you find a better translation, and/or tell folks which specific document you are quoting from?

@keshlam This quote from Guattari appears as written in Fashionable Nonsense (the English edition of the French Impostures intellectuelles). If it reads like meaningless intellectual word salad... that's the whole point they were trying to make by quoting that.

@NotThatGuy: Then I'm missing something;I'm not sure what question is being asked.

@keshlam I think that it is not a translation issue. I'm pretty sure that the nonsense is already in the French original.

See Dawkins' review of Alan Sokal and Jean Bricmont's Intellectual Impostures (aka: Fashionable Nonsense, published in French in 1997):

This is a quotation from the psychoanalyst Félix Guattari, one of many fashionable French 'intellectuals' outed by Alan Sokal and Jean Bricmont in their splendid book Intellectual Impostures, previously published in French and now released in a completely rewritten and revised English edition. Guattari goes on indefinitely in this vein and offers, in the opinion of Sokal and Bricmont, "the most brilliant mélange of scientific, pseudo-scientific and philosophical jargon that we have ever encountered".

Thus, no fallacy at all, but a violation of Grice's Maxims about avoiding obscurity and ambiguity.
See Paul Grice's Cooperative principle.

I see. Influenced by dadaism, perhaps.
